# Office Add-In : Office.auth.getAccessToken Not work on mobile web browsers

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I have simply Office Excel Web Addin from Visual Studio 2022 which is my base code for development. I have implemented one function which is based on authentication with Office SSO and then Behalf authentication flow on the server side, but first step matters the most - Fetch Access token from Office Context. Here is fragment of my code:

```
async function GetAccessToken() {
        try {
            console.log("Start to fetch behalf token");
            var behalfToken = "";
            var accessToken = "";
            await Office.auth.getAccessToken({
                allowSignInPrompt: true,
                allowConsentPrompt: true,
                forMSGraphAccess: true
            }).then(officeResponse => {
                if (officeResponse.error) {
                    console.log(response);
                } else {
                    behalfToken = officeResponse
                }
            });
            console.log("Got behalf token");

            console.log("Fetch access token")
            const url = "https://myazurewebiste-site1.atempurl.com/onbehalf"
            const headers = { 'Authorization': `${behalfToken}` };

            accessToken = await Http("GET", url, headers)


            console.log("We got accessToken")

            return accessToken.access_token;

        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Wystąpił błąd:", error.message);
        }
    }
```

This is method responsible for office auth. Its works perfectly on desktop and browser version of Excel but only od WINDOWS or MacOS. On EDGE Mobile on iPadOS it's not working or safari same thing. Didnt tried other tablets or phones.

Here is error on Edge inspect on mobile :
[image: Edge Console log on Mobile Device]

Tried many browser i could: Edge, Safari, Brave etc. (but most of them are on CHromium so same thing).
Tried read something about that but its fiasco.
Try change code but in every way on Desktop works perfectly, on mobile fails.

Comment: Office JS SSO should work on mobile. Could you please raise an issue on the product repo (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues)?

Comment: Ok thanks very much!